# How to get item id and target parent id(container id) when drag and drop item using dragula js

Tags: php, jquery, drag-and-drop, dragula

I am using Dragula JavaScript to dynamically append the container items. When I drag and drop, I want to get the target parent id and item id. I have attached the image with the same. Once I get these id's I want to store them in database. I am using PHP and AJAX.

```
function drop(item, target) {
  var parent = getParent(item);
  if (_copy && o.copySortSource && target === _source) {
    parent.removeChild(_item);
  }
  if (isInitialPlacement(target)) {
    drake.emit('cancel', item, _source, _source);
  } else {
    drake.emit('drop', item, target, _source, _currentSibling);

  }
  cleanup();
}
```

[image: drag and drop image]

Answer (score 1):

I have got my solution..tried as below..its working like a charm..

```
function drop(item, target) {
var parent = getParent(item);
if (_copy && o.copySortSource && target === _source) {
parent.removeChild(_item);
}
if (isInitialPlacement(target)) {
drake.emit('cancel', item, _source, _source);
var itemid=item.id;
var targetid = target.id;

//initialize function to update status
update_function(itemid, targeid); //this function called in main page
} else {
drake.emit('drop', item, target, _source, _currentSibling);
var itemid=item.id;
var targetid = target.id;

//initialize function to update status
update_function(itemid, targeid); //this function called in main page
}
cleanup();
}
```